# How to randomly choose one of many objects to be added to an array list?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, interface

Say I have 4 objects and I am looking to populate an arraylist of 100 elements with these four objects. Basically each time we add an elements to the arraylist, there is a 1 in 4 chance each element will be chosen. I thought of one way to do it but I think there is a better, more "pretty" & effective way

just rough pseudo-code to help explain

```
for(int i = 0; i != 100; i++){
    Random generator = new Random();
    int i = generator.nextInt(4); // this will give us 0,1,2,or 3
        if(i ==0){
            arraylist.add(object1(param1, param2));
        }
    // etc.. continues with 3 other else if statments and objects
```

ideas? All the other objects I have also share the same interface, if that can help us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an array containing the four objects:

```
Object[] objects = new Object[] {
  object1(param1, param2),
  object2(param1),
  object3(param1, param2, param3, param4),
  object4(param1, param2)
}
```

Then adjust your code:

```
Random generator = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  int j = generator.nextInt(4); // this will give us 0,1,2,or 3
  arraylist.add(objects[j]);
  // etc.. continues with 3 other else if statments and objects
}
```

Notice that you don't have to create a new generator on every iteration - you can create it just once and reuse the same instance.

Comment: How would you specify their parameters? Note that some of them have 2, some have 3, etc

Comment: Check the edited answer. You can use those parameters when you create the objects for the first time.

Comment: Thanks for editing it. What if the paramaters are a function that returns a random number? Each time an object is created, will the function that returns a random number (passed as their param) be called? Hopefully I am making sense

Comment: Parameters in Java cannot be functions. What you can do is is add a method to those objects. That method can return a random value every time. For example, object1 would be a `new RandomGenerator(param1, param2)` which would have a method called `public int getNewRandom()` method that returns something like `return generator.nextInt()`. Then every time that getNewRandom() is called, it would return a different value despite the RandomGenerator object being the same.

Comment: Well right now I have `arraylist.add(new object(randomDouble(),randomDouble(),randomDouble()));` and it works fine

Comment: Haha right, but thats not what I want. That's the code I have above that I am trying to fix. I want to do an array of objects like you gave me and each time one is called, to get new values for params by calling a function. Is the only way I can do that by doing what you said in your previous comment? Edit: Like you said, it isn't letting me pass the function in for paramaters in the object list. ugh.. Edit2: Actually it worked, i didnt have the new keyword infront of the object, but i dont think it will get new random values each time it is called.. ill try and let you know

Comment: Gotcha. I don't see a better solution than moving the logic that generates the random numbers into the objects themselves. You could also use a static method as a factory of objects, which would probably make your code simpler and easier to read (e.g. `ObjectFactory.newObject(objectType)`.

Comment: I dont know if you saw my edits to my comment but it didnt work. I think I am just going to stick with what I had originally. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63264/discussion-between-frosty-and-mike-laren).